# Calling a class method from a callback function in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, this

I'm having problem with the scope of 'this' in JS.
I have a callback function that calls a method (connectSensor). In that method, I try to change a member of the class using 'this'. However, I get
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAllListeners()' of undefined".
I think because the method is called from inside the callback, 'this' no longer refers to the class, but I don't know how to solve it (i.e. have a reference to the class inside connectSensor). I'm using RPi 4 and Linux.

```
/* Perhipheral MAC. */
const SENSOR_MAC = "aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa";
class ble{

constructor(){
        this.noble = require('noble');
        this.sensor;    
}

createEventHandlers(){

        var noble = this.noble;

        
        noble.on('stateChange', function(state)
        {
                /* Start scanning if Bluetooth is on. */  
                if( state == 'poweredOn' ) noble.startScanning();

        });

        noble.on('discover', function(peripheral){
                if (perhipheral.address == SENSOR_MAC){
                        noble.stopScanning();
                        this.sensor = peripheral;
                        console.log("Discovered the sensor: " + this.sensor.name)
                        /* Here 'this' is bound to the class. */
                        this.connectSensor();
                }

        }.bind(this));
}

connectSensor(){
            /* I want 'this' here to always refer to the class. */
            this.sensor.removeAllListeners();
}

}
```

Usage:

```
bleClass = new ble();
bleClass.createEventHandlers();
```

Comment: Have you actually confirmed that `peripheral` is not `undefined`?

Comment: I think so. When I comment "this.connectSensor();", the program prints "Discovered the sensor." and stays there. When I uncomment it I get the error, but interestingly the message is not printed. I'm not sure why. (I have to admit that I don't know how JE engine works).

Comment: So "sensor" is defined in the callback as I don't get an "... of undefined" error when using "this.sensor.name", but in "connectSensor", "this" (whatever it refers to) does not have a "sensor" member/is undefined.

Comment: What version of node and noble are you using? You can check with `node -v` and `npm ls noble` respectively.

Comment: node 8.11.1 and noble 1.9.1.

Comment: It appears I don't have a compatible Bluetooth 4.0 USB adapter, so I can't reproduce the issue unfortunately. I know this isn't your entire code though because you don't have a call to `noble.startScanning();` anywhere. Can you provide a [mcve]? Emphasis on _minimal_ and _reproducible_. Don't just copy your entire project into the question, but try to provide enough to where someone meeting the system requirements could reproduce the issue without editing your code.

Comment: Interesting... as far as I can tell, what you have _should_ work.

Comment: *""this" (whatever it refers to) does not have a "sensor" member/is undefined."* What is the value of `this` in `connectSensor`?

Answer (score 0):

I now realize the problem was that the connectSensor in my code (but not in the question) was outside the "if" statement. Therefore, the first BLE device to be discovered (which was never the intended sensor) did not have the "sensor" member initialized, and hence the error. In the end this had nothing to do with the scope of 'this' or JavaScript.
I sincerely regret wasting everybody's time.